# Center Children to absolute full size parent

Tags: javascript, css, parent-child

Below code should be responsive and work with IE9+ unfortunately.

I have a parent (levelA) at the bottom of my test page, which should overlay all other html elements, whilst  always being full window width and full window height. In this example peachpuff color.

The goal is to center the child, in this case an image (levelC) horizontally and vertically in the center of it's parent. (levelA)
The image has a fixed size but the dimensions can vary between 150x150 and 900x750.

A pure CSS solution would be highly appreciated.

```js
(function() {
   console.log("ready");
})();
```

```css
#levelA {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
#levelB {

}
#levelC {

}
```

```html
  <div id="main">
        <h1>Test site</h1>

        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>
        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>
        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="right upper">
            <a href="#">A</a>
            <a href="#">B</a>
            <a href="#">C</a>
            <a href="#">D</a>
        </div>
        <div class="left upper">
            <p>
                <a href="#">News</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Faq</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <div id="levelA" class="levelA">
      <div id="levelB" class="levelB">
        <img id="levelC" class="levelC" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

If it is not possible to solve via CSS only, I could implement a little bit of JavaScript magic.

Do you guys have any tips?

Comment: Is that image responsive or it shall always be 150x150?

Comment: `#levelB { position: static; } #levelC { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%) }` this will make `#levelC` to be always in the middle of the `#levelA` no matter what size it has (because of transform).

Comment: Level A is not the parent but the grandparent of level C. Do you want B to be centered (including C).

Comment: @Gerard Whatever is easier. I just included levelB as a helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to provide support for ie9+, you can't use CSS3 `transform` property and you'll end up using javascript, so you can write a simple function to vertically align an element.

```js
(function() {
   function vAlign(el) {
     el = document.querySelector(el);
     if (el.clientHeight) {
       el.style.position = 'absolute';
       el.style.left = el.style.right = el.style.bottom = 0;
       el.style.top = '50%';
       el.style.margin = '-'+ el.clientHeight / 2 +'px auto';
     } 
   }

   vAlign('#levelC');
})();
```

```css
#levelA {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
  <div id="main">
        <h1>Test site</h1>

        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>
        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>
        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="right upper">
            <a href="#">A</a>
            <a href="#">B</a>
            <a href="#">C</a>
            <a href="#">D</a>
        </div>
        <div class="left upper">
            <p>
                <a href="#">News</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Faq</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <div id="levelA" class="levelA">
      <div id="levelB" class="levelB">
        <img id="levelC" class="levelC" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: good answer, howerver, if the image is not always 150px, you can replace 
  `margin-top: -75px;`    by    `transform: translateX(-50%);`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunately the size of the image can vary and is not always 150x150.

Comment: @AppRoyale that's why I asked you in the comments before, and you replied "image has a fixed size", in that case, you'll need to use javascript. Let me edit my question with the function you need.

Comment: @AppRoyale no need to use javascript, just see my comment above yours ;)

Comment: I am really sorry for the confusion. I was not quite clear. I meant the image should not be responsive and can be static. The image dimensions can vary though as they won't be always 150x150 but could also be 900x750 e.g.

Comment: @Neil that should work only if he's not targeting old browsers like ie < 11.
AppRoyale if that's not a limitation for you, I mean, supporting only ie11+, then you can replace that line as Neil said.

Comment: IE9 is mandatory unfortunately.
When I try the solution of Neil it doesn't seem to be very "centrish".
http://jsbin.com/saboyexuzo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: The `#levelC` rules seem to be off, why give both `left` and `right` (and top and bottom) with a value of 0? Instead use:`#levelC { position: absolute; left: 50%; margin: 0 auto; top: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); }`

Comment: @SaschaM78 that won't center the image horizontally, you'll move it way to the right.

Comment: @Frondor: no, just have a look [here](http://jsbin.com/tecehut/1/edit?html,css,output) and enable/disable the "HTML" and "CSS" outputs to see it work.

Comment: Both examples are working for me. I've now added a JS function to vertically center the image. **It supports ie9+** now

Comment: @AppRoyale be sure you're not overriding the same styles that this function handles in your css. Try this from your phone and check if something goes wrong https://fiddle.jshell.net/j2n9jhcn/show/light/ looks fine to me. (I'm not styling `#levelC` at all, since js does all the job)

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my question and I will vote for your answer.
However I wasn't thinking about a #levelCC, which is on the same level as #levelC and which is a simple text, that should be displayed right below the picture. Is that somehow possible with your approach?
See below fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ccvt7vLs/

Comment: @AppRoyale Well, that's a totally different question and should be addressed separately. I limited myself to solve the problem you presented at first. But yes, it's totally possible by wrapping the "levels" within a `<div>`, Anyway, I fixed the fiddle for you: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ccvt7vLs/1/ Does it works now? You'll probably need to set some `opacity` and `z-index` to make it look good..

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
   console.log("ready");
})();
```

```css
#levelA {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
#levelB {

}
#levelC {
     position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
  <div id="main">
        <h1>Test site</h1>

        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>
        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>
        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>

        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ul>
        <p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. <em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em>            Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, <code>commodo vitae</code>, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum
            orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. <a href="#">Donec non enim</a> in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis.</p>

        <h2>Header Level 2</h2>

        <ol>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
            <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
        </ol>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus magna. Cras in mi at felis aliquet congue. Ut a est eget ligula molestie gravida. Curabitur massa. Donec eleifend, libero at sagittis mollis, tellus est malesuada tellus, at
                luctus turpis elit sit amet quam. Vivamus pretium ornare est.</p>
        </blockquote>

        <h3>Header Level 3</h3>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div class="right upper">
            <a href="#">A</a>
            <a href="#">B</a>
            <a href="#">C</a>
            <a href="#">D</a>
        </div>
        <div class="left upper">
            <p>
                <a href="#">News</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Faq</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <div id="levelA" class="levelA">
      <div id="levelB" class="levelB">
        <img id="levelC" class="levelC" src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```